# HPE UFT is interfering with java configuration in the machine

Tags: java, qtp, jnlp

Only this fixed my error:

> If you are not able to launch a jnlp application after installing UFT
>   on you machine, Just uninstall UFT and try to launch the application
>   and then install UFT

I am not sure what to do when this issue is back as I didn't really solve the issue structurally. My question is what could have made this behavior possible? During the issue phase, I was not even able to launch Java Control Panel (.cnpl) or javaws instance for any jnlp. changing the environment variables also didn't work. Reinstalling Java also didn't.

Comment: It might be environment variables that are coming in between, can you use cmd and try running the jnlp using "javaws" command and see what happens.

Comment: Tried that, Nothing happens, I see java popover (which should ideally be showing the status of opening the jnlp) for a jiffy and closes itself. Also tried uninstalling and installing Java multiple times. Tried using also jdk instead of jre alone.

Comment: Generally 2 environment variables of UFT which affect java are JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and _JAVA_OPTIONS (which you should see even when you do java -version). Try setting them to blank in cmd using the set commands and then traverse to the bin folder of java and try using the javaws command to run the jnlp, I think by doing this you should remove all the possibilities of UFT interfering with Java.

I am able to run jnlp and uft together in my work

Comment: @user5612655 True, Environmental variables is the culprit.

Comment: Did it fix your issue? if so we can post that as an answer so it will be useful for others

Comment: Yes, Issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables that UFT adds by default for Java Add-In might be causing issue.

Try removing or renaming JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variables, although if you want to load Java Add-in support for your application these environment variables are needed.

Read below for more information:

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/Checking_Java_EnvironmentVariables_Settings.htm